# InnoDB - Losing mysql transaction data - InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

I am trying to do a small application in php and mysql.

**Problem:**
The database gets corrupted and I am losing data randomly.
The data that is always lost is part of a transaction, never a complete transaction, just part of the transaction.

**Info about the application:**
Wampserver is used for the basic setup on a Windows 7 Machine.
The machine is a personal desktop.
The application will not be hosted online, it will always run of a local server.

This is part of the log from mysql

```
121108 19:19:57 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
121109 10:09:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121109 10:09:56 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
121109 10:09:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 659637, file name .\mysql-bin.000056
121109 10:09:58  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121109 10:09:59 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 6158775
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
121109 10:09:59 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
121109 10:09:59 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121109 10:09:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121109 10:09:59 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

This is the code I am using - 
[PHP CODE](https://github.com/lazyguy/Event-management/blob/master/addParticipant.php)

Please note :

- I am not sure if it is a problem with my code or something else.
- The Code is not good, this is the first time i am writing more than 2 lines of PHP.
- The code that needs to be checked is from line 11 to line 198
- The mysql query for data that is lost is at line number 176

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the issue that MySQL is crashing or that your transaction isn't working?

Comment: When the transaction is done, the data is in the database. I after some time sometimes hours sometimes days sometimes after shutdown, ' the data disappears. When I checked the log I got the above. What I am not sure is if there is something wrong with my code or if it is mysql or wamp in general.